# systemd best practices, structuring of project

Tags: linux, systemd, drivers

Say I have a couple drivers, a few C++ applications that use those, and then several Java applications that interact with the C++ applications.  What I have gathered so far...

drivers.target

```
[Unit]
Description=Drivers Target
# No contents, just a target for driver services to "register" with
```

driver-apps.target

```
[Unit]
Description=Driver-dependent Applications Target
Wants=drivers.target
After=drivers.target
```

project-apps.target

```
[Unit]
Description(non-driver-dependent) Applications Target
Wants=drivers-apps.target
After=drivers-apps.target
```

my-driver.service

```
[Unit]
Description=My Driver
[Service]
Type=oneshot
... # Script that starts driver, with a 'stop' script as well
RemainAfterExit=yes
[Install]
WantedBy=drivers.target
```

cpp-app.service

```
[Unit]
Description=C++ Application
ReloadPropagatedFrom=driver-apps.target
PartOf=driver-apps.target
[Service]
...
[Install]
WantedBy=driver-apps.target
```

cpp-app.service

```
[Unit]
Description=C++ Application
ReloadPropagatedFrom=driver-apps.target
PartOf=driver-apps.target
[Service]
...
[Install]
WantedBy=driver-apps.target
```

java-app.service

```
[Unit]
Description=C++ Application
ReloadPropagatedFrom=driver-apps.target
PartOf=driver-apps.target
[Service]
...
[Install]
WantedBy=project-apps.target
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

What I have found is that I have to tie SOMETHING to multit-user.target or a similar high-level target.  Is this the proper structure to get everything going at startup?

Comment: Yes - you need to give it a target to aim for. But you only need systemd if you need to have programs up and running without any user intervention.